# A graph where the vertices are a subset but the edges are not?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm interested in knowing if there is a name for a graph G where;

Its vertices:

- Are a subset of the vertices of graph H.
- Are the terminal vertices of paths in H.

Its edges:

- Are only incident to the terminal vertices of paths in H.

Comment: Sounds like an auxiliary graph construction, which often depends on the context and have no specific names.

Comment: @kleinbottle Okay, good to know that there might not be an answer. I'm not that well-versed in Graph Theory yet so I'm trying to make sure I've got the correct terminology.